# Python logging file handler not using specified handler

Tags: python, logging

I am using a logger.conf file included below where I have two loggers three if you count root. OnPremLog is used in normal circumstances and I just recently created TestingLog for handling automated unit testing that requires to run the code not in the normal operational environment. When I implemented this new logger I now have a handler for each.

The issue is when I was running my OnPremCode using that logger as usual, the file handler is now behaving as if it was the testing handler (it is writing instead of appending). I want the test logger to just overwrite the log each time but normal operations I have dozens of scripts that write to the same log and should append. First is my implementation of the logger from a snippet of actual code then the conf file in entirety.

For those that want more background this is running on python 3.7 on windows and the automated build happens on some docker image of linux but that is not the issue being dealt with.

Implementation:

```
logging.logFileFullPath = cfg.LogsFolder + cfg.onPremLogFile + T_STAMP + '.log'
logging.config.fileConfig(cfg.ScriptsFolder + cfg.LogConfFile)
LOGGER = logging.getLogger('OnPremLog')
```

After seeing the similar question and answer to it pointing to case sensitivity I checked and my references are case correct.

Conf File:

```
[loggers]
keys=root,OnPremLog,TestingLog

[handlers]
keys=MainHand,OnPremHand,TestingHand

[formatters]
keys=MainForm

[logger_root]
level=NOTSET
handlers=MainHand

[logger_OnPremLog]
level=INFO
handlers=OnPremHand
qualname=OnPremLog
propagate=0

[logger_TestingLog]
level=INFO
handlers=TestingHand
qualname=TestingLog
propagate=0

[handler_MainHand]
class=StreamHandler
level=WARNING
formatter=MainForm
args=(sys.stdout,)

[handler_OnPremHand]
class=FileHandler
level=INFO
formatter=MainForm
args=(logFileFullPath, 'a')

[handler_TestingHand]
class=FileHandler
level=INFO
formatter=MainForm
args=(logFileFullPath, 'w')

[formatter_MainForm]
format=GACF~%(asctime)s~%(levelname)s~%(filename)s~%(name)s~%(message)s
datefmt=
class=logging.Formatter
```

Comment: Ok I think I determined the issue. I thought if the handler wasn't being used it wouldn't affect the others. It appears since I am using the same variable for the log path that both file handlers get defined and the last one is what affected my log file even though I use the OnPremLog. Not sure how I want to or what I must do to correct this (two different config files or some other method)

Comment: for now I am implementing a separate conf file to use for when the unit testing is performed. Define such using a passed in argument flag unless there is a better practice someone points me in the direction of.